# RESTEasy - some method URL addresses doesn't work

Tags: java, rest, jboss, path, resteasy

The problem is very simple but that means more strange.

I have method defined as followed (for example)

```
@GET
@GZIP
@Path("/v2/something/anything/goes/here")
void getData(@BeanParam ApiCommonRequest req) throws Exception;
```

When calling this URL address by remote host, JBoss responds: "Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost/rest/v2/something/anything/goes/here"

The funny part is (after few hours of investigating I found out) that **WHEN i change URL beginning (in server @Path definition) from "/v2" to "/v3", it finnaly works normally.**

So following totally works:

```
@GET
@GZIP
@Path("/v3/something/anything/goes/here")
void getData(@BeanParam ApiCommonRequest req) throws Exception;
```

I tried every thinkable combinations and no "v2" and similar are not THE specific problem - It's bothered by other URL addresses as well - without much sense what specifically is wrong with it.

It even helped separating URL parts to diferent @Path annotatitions - meaning: when *I had THE SAME URL working and not working - only by putting part of the URL to the parent class @Path definition*. That "fixed it" also (once again - the same URL address working and not working influenced by @Path annotation written a bit differently). So this seems to mean that there cannot be problem with the URL address as such - like with some URLRewrite configuration. (which I also checked out, if there could be some conflict)

So this doesn't work:

```
@Path("/rest")
public interface MyAPI {
  @GET
  @GZIP
  @Path("/v2/something/anything/goes/here")
  void getData(@BeanParam ApiCommonRequest req) throws Exception;
}
```

But this works!:

```
@Path("/rest/v2")
public interface MyAPI {
  @GET
  @GZIP
  @Path("/something/anything/goes/here")
  void getData(@BeanParam ApiCommonRequest req) throws Exception;
}
```

Need to change "/v2/something/anything/goes/here" to "/v3/something/anything/goes/here" doesn't make any sense and is not really a solution.

Can this be some RESTEasy JBOSS bug? I did invest really a lot of time digging through internet for similar problems/bugs of JBOSS - but nothing similar found. I find hard to believe that there even can be bug in this simple (basic usage) example.

- One thing, which could be helpful is some way to observe JBOSS RestEasy method installation during bootup for some error messages or any log entry? No error found in logs from JBOSS.

Thanks for help.

P.S. When I made reflection-based REST documentation using *@Context Dispatcher* (I grabbed all available REST methods through JBOSS) these non working URL methods ARE there normally mentioned as deployed :-))

Comment: Could you show exactly how you've received all REST methods?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this will help, but I've had similar problem. [This](http://bill.burkecentral.com/2013/05/29/the-poor-jax-rs-request-dispatching-algorithm/) article may help you. After reading it all I've found solution to all my problems. Answer was to switch from resteasy version 3.0.9.Final back to 2.3.5.Final. It's not perfect, in fact it's ugly but it works pretty well...

Answer (score 1):

I've found out source of the problem (maybe related only for JBoss RestEasy):

When you annotate interface with URL prefix like @Path("/rest/v1") and then you annotate separate methods with @Path("/store/items/...") which should produce resource at URL "/rest/store/v1/items/..." , problem arises, when you create another interface file with same prefix annotation (e.g. /rest/v1/). They are then in conflict and one of them is ignored.

Solution is to have **only one instance of the same interface path**. So only one file with @Path("/rest/store") e.g.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that there is some other REST or Servlet resource deployed in your app that gets matched for the problematic "/v2/something" path.
Is MyApi the only JAX-RS resource in your app?

How did you define the root URL for the JAX-RS container(it seems to be "/" in your case)? Do you have an `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` or do you map the REST paths in web.xml? Can you switch the JAX-RS root path to some other value like "/jaxrs/test/".

Generally these errors are caused by path matching algorithm and incorrect mapping of REST resources. For example conflicting servlet/JAXRS mapping.

Some further questions: Where does your resteasy run(application server, tomcat, etc)? 
Can you isolate the problem(create an empty web app with just one JAXRS class and one methods)? 
Are you bundling some other custom libraries with your deployment? Do you access you server via some HTTP proxy like apache,nginx? If so, do you any rewriting, pattern matching defined there?